# What's causing these javascript validation errors (Implied global and already defined var)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation

Could anyone explain me why:

```
function doAjax() {
    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    try { // Firefox, Opera 8.0+ and Safari
        xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e) { // Internet Explorer
        try {
            xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX. Please use an AJAX compatible browser.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    xmlHttpReq.open('GET', 'handler.php', true);
    xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
            var response = xmlHttpReq.responseText;
            handleAjaxResponse(response);
        }
    };
    xmlHttpReq.send(null);
    return true;
}
```

is causing the following validation errors:

```
Error:

Implied global: ActiveXObject 8, XMLHttpRequest 4, alert 15, handleAjaxResponse 24

Problem at line 10 character 16: 'e' is already defined.

catch (e) {

Problem at line 14 character 20: 'e' is already defined.

catch (e) {
```

by the JSlint.com javascript validator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be more sensible to use framework like jQuery (especially if you seriously want to support older versions of IE (pre v6) ) but I'll assume there is a reason you're not doing that.

It would be better if a) you don't nest try-catches and b) you factored out a set of  functions namely one to get an Xhr object, another to use an Xhr object to make a generic ajax request and an outer "doAjax" function that performs the specific ajax call you want to make:-

```
function getXHR()
{
    var result = null
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        result = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        try { result = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0") }
        catch (e) { }

        if (result == null)
        {
            try { result = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") }
            catch (e) { }
        }
    }
    return result; 
}


function ajaxRequest(url, data, callBack)
{
    var xmlHttpReq = getXHR();
    if (xmlHttpReq)
    {
        xmlHttpReq.open(data != null ? 'GET' : 'POST', url, true);
        xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4)
            {
                //what happens if status is not 200
                callBack(xmlHttpReq.responseText);
            }
        };
        xmlHttpReq.send(null);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function doAjax()
{
     var result = ajaxRequest('handler.php', null, handleAjaxResponse);
     if (!result) alert("Your browser does not support AJAX. Please use an AJAX compatible browser.");
     return result;
}
```

A futher refinement would be to make the callback accept an XHR object rather than the basic responseText.  This would give you more flexibility.  If the callback function simply wants the text it can use  this function:-

```
function getTextFromXhr(xhr)
{
    xhr.onreadystatechange = fnVoid;
    if (xhr.status == 200)
    {
        return xhr.responseText;
    }
    else
    {
        throw {number: xhr.status,
            description: xhr.statusText,
            responseText: xhr.responseText
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the **first error**, here is an [exerpt from the JSLint Documentation](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html):

> **Undefined Variables and Functions**
>
> JavaScript's biggest problem is its
>   dependence on global variables,
>   particularly implied global variables.
>   If a variable is not explicitly
>   declared (usually with the var
>   statement), then JavaScript assumes
>   that the variable was global. This can
>   mask misspelled names and other
>   problems.
>
> JSLint expects that all variables and
>   functions are declared before they are
>   used or invoked. This allows it to
>   detect implied global variables. It is
>   also good practice because it makes
>   programs easier to read.
>
> Sometimes a file is dependent on
>   global variables and functions that
>   are defined elsewhere. You can
>   identify these to JSLint by including
>   a comment in your file that lists the
>   global functions and objects that your
>   program depends on, but that are not
>   defined in your program or script
>   file.
>
> A global declaration can look like
>   this:

```
/*global getElementByAttribute, breakCycles, hanoi */
```

> A global declaration starts with
>   `/*global`. Notice that there is no
>   space before the g. You can have as
>   many `/*global` comments as you like.
>   They must appear before the use of the
>   variables they specify.

**Regarding your problem, the following section is most likely to help you fix the errors:**

> Some globals can be predefined for
>   you. Select the Assume a browser
>   (browser) option (see Options below)
>   to predefine the standard global
>   properties that are supplied by web
>   browsers, such as window and document
>   and alert. Select the Assume Rhino
>   (rhino) option to predefine the global
>   properties provided by the Rhino
>   environment. Select the Assume a Yahoo
>   Widget (widget) option to predefine
>   the global properties provided by the
>   Yahoo! Widgets environment.

The **second error** is given because you re-use the variable "`e`" for each exception, including the nested ones. Rename the variables on each exception to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks, though the "assume a browser" does not seem to fix the implied global error - adding a custom note just for a validator seems rather strange to me, theoretically, there is nothing bad about my way of doing things then? aka, it's actually valid?

Answer (score 3):

You are reusing the variable e in each try/catch block.  Try renaming them to avoid the collision.  The other issues are just warnings that you are using things that need to be defined elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, so renaming the Es to eg. e1, e2 and e3 would be cleaner? It doesn't seem very clean to me - and the above example is copied from W3C I believe.

Comment: No, renaming the 'e's would not be "cleaner".  JSLint shows errors and warnings.  These are simply warnings that by using 'e' you are making the previous error object unavailable in that block.  If you needed the first 'e' in the second catch you would want to rename.  I would ignore this warning.

Comment: I would also avoid nesting try-catches.

Answer (score 1):

JSlint usually give a LOT of errors...

'e' is already defined seems pretty clear to me:) you use the same variable for all your try-catch statements.